# Closing wxPython app on a separated thread runs into a window alert

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, wxpython, cefpython

I have a Flask-SocketIO server, which initialize a GUI in a separated thread.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'dev':
        print "Running Flask-SocketIO on dev mode"
    else:
        print "Running Flask-SocketIO on production mode"
        print 'Running Graphical User Interface...'
        thread.start_new_thread(display_react.main, ())
        print 'Initializing server'

    socketio.run(app, debug=False)
```

The GUI is basically the cefpthon3 example which use the wxPython, but instead of being a normal browser, it only shows up a specific page served by the server. At the moment i want the whole app shutdown when i close the GUI. For the effect, i've created a route on the server which (when called) will shutdown the server.

```
@app.route('/shutdown', methods=['GET'])
def shutdown():
    server_request.shutdown()
    socketio.stop()
    print "Trying to close..."
    return 'Server shutting down...'
```

And this route is called when before close the wxPython.
However, this error appears before the server shutdown:
[image]

Can anyone help me solving or hiding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wxPython almost always has to be the main thread, which is most likely why you are seeing this error that is asserting on `wxIsMainThread`. One somewhat easy workaround would be to start wxPython as the main thread / application and have it run Flask in a thread.

I think that will work better. You can ask on the wxPython Google group for other workarounds though.

Comment: Yes, I dont know if this is the best way. But it is a workaround for sure and it works! Thank you!!